# Inline require() working in requirejs but not with optimized almond build

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, almond

As the title says my inline require calls are working in a non-optimized requirejs run but not working when built with grunt and almondjs.

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing views/some/view
```

The top of any file might be:

```
define(
['jquery', 'app'],
function($, App) {
```

and later on based on business logic I want to be able to require another file

```
require(['views/some/view'], function(SomeView){
     console.log(SomeView);
});
```

I tried the alternative syntax as well:

```
var SomeView= require('views/some/view');
```

And this all works using an unbuilt requirejs version. But again it fails when I build it with grunt and almond

```
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                name: "../components/almond/almond", 
                baseUrl: "src",
                mainConfigFile: "./require.config.js",
                include: ['main'], 
                insertRequire: ['main'], // Add a require step in at the end for the main module.
                wrap: true, // Wrap everything up in a closure
                generateSourceMaps: true, // Experimental
                preserveLicenseComments: false, // Needs turned off for generateSourceMaps
                optimize: "uglify2", // Supports generateSourceMaps
                out: "assets/javascripts/build.js"
            }
        }
    },
```

I can get it working fine in almond if I put it up at the top of the file in a define call, but isn't it preferable in AMD to keep it lean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Almond documentation it works best with non-dynamic loading and everything packaged into the one file.

You should be able to set "findNestedDependencies" to true in your compile options to ensure that your inline require calls are included as part of the build.