# Excluding file from optimizing in Durandal build

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, grunt-contrib-requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I'm using Grunt to build the [Durandal starter kit pro](https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/HTMLStarterKitPro) package.

It all works fine, except for one tiny detail. I would like to exclude one file (`app-config` below) from the optimizer and keep it as a non minified file when my build is done.

Based on other SO thread suggestions, I'm currently excluding it using `empty:`, which removes it from the optimized file as expected. However, when I open the built project I get an error in the console:

`Uncaught Error: main missing app-config`

```
options: {
    name: '../lib/require/almond-custom',
    baseUrl: requireConfig.baseUrl,
    mainPath: 'app/main',
    paths: mixIn({ }, requireConfig.paths, { 
         'almond': 'lib/require/almond-custom', 
         'app-config': 'empty:' 
    }),
    optimize: 'none',
    out: 'build/app/main.js',
    preserveLicenseComments: false
}
```

Is almond the problem? I tried switching it to the full requirejs using `include: ['path/to/require']`, without success.

If you want to reproduce it locally you can either download the starter kit from the above link, or use a [slightly configurated version](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ae7lu18jyl6cqvx/AAATzb9XcNkMLEETeLKCJF9Ya?dl=0) which is closer to my example. Just run an `npm install` in the folder and you're all set.

Comment: So, I'm _sure_ you've already looked at this, and I'm not even really familiar with durandal, but on the [github page](https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/HTMLStarterKitPro), in the `options` object, they show a property called `exclude` that accepts an array...

Comment: @anied Thanks for the tip. Yes, I have tried both `empty:` and the exclude property, both resulting in the same exception.

Answer (score 3):

I have downloaded you [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ae7lu18jyl6cqvx/AAATzb9XcNkMLEETeLKCJF9Ya?dl=0) and do the following steps.

1. Extract zip file, open `cmd` and change the directory to this folder.
2. Run `npm install` to install all the dependencies.
3. Run `grunt` to start to build the project.

And when I open http://localhost:8999/ and saw the alert `1` which is `alert(appConfig.foo);` in your `main.js`.
After clicked `Ok` to hide the alert, the web page works fines. Any more input for you ?

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

So I am not sure how you are facing with this issue.

Comment: It's important that you run the `grunt build` task and not the default `grunt` task to try the build :) Sorry about not mentioning that.

Comment: I saw it problem, but haven't seen any wrong here. If I remove completely app-config on your paths definition and passing into define as '../app-config.js', It works fine but the app-config.js is included in the main.js. Let me think a bit more.
I have no idea what is Almond but you might wish to see this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515872/inline-require-working-in-requirejs-but-not-with-optimized-almond-build

Comment: If almond is the problem it's possible to use requirejs instead. It's included in the `lib` folder too...

Comment: Just guessing since I haven't' used it before.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference of the `durandal` issues found in this particular link
[grunt-durandal](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-durandal/issues/1)

The main module controls the implementation of the `durandal services` 
The link can be found in `main.js`

Here you can see the system.debug(true).You can remove it as written in the post here [document](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MostCommonASPNETSupportIssuesReportingFromDeepInsideMicrosoftDeveloperSupport.aspx).

The function as quoted in the article `Overrides request execution timeout making it effectively infinite`.

Also while using uglify in grunt the debug is set to false as per the documentation.

As per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-durandal) you need to set the system.debug(false)

Hope this might help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
....
paths: mixIn({ }, requireConfig.paths, { 
     'almond': ['lib/require/almond-custom', '!lib/require/almond-custom/app-config.js']
}),
....
```

just note the second path of `app-config.js` is correct. I think you should find your way, the above is a hint, if not a direct solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate what this actually does?